# How do I change where a plugin pulls updates from?

Tags: plugins, filters, updates

I'm trying to write a custom plugin for a few of my clients, and I'd like to serve updates for this plugin from my own server. I tried doing some research on how to do this, but everything I find is stuff like "how to update WordPress."

How can I change where a plugin checks for updates?

Comment: At the top of the main plugin file, in the comments, the 'Plugin URI' is where WP will check for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below a link to a custom update checker for WordPress plugins. Useful if you don't want to host your project in the official WP repository, but would still like it to support automatic updates. It also works with themes.

Plugin Update Checker: https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker